# Eclipse not publishing web.xml filled by Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, eclipse-wtp, m2e-wtp

Continuing my prior question ([Maven: how to fill a variable in web.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566267/maven-how-to-fill-a-variable-in-web-xml-file)), I realized that the values written in `web.xml` are not passed to the deployed `web.xml`.
Let me show what is happening: I am running a web application in Tomcat through WTP Eclipse. In the `web.xml`, I have this `context-param`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>producao</param-name>
    <param-value>${ambiente.producao}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The `ambiente.producao` is filled according to Maven profile chosen:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <ambiente.producao>true</ambiente.producao>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>desenv</id>
        <properties>
            <ambiente.producao>false</ambiente.producao>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Also, I have a `ServletContextListener` implementation which will print the value of the `producao` param:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    logger.warn(event.getServletContext().getInitParameter("producao"));
}
```

Thanks to Fred Bricon tip, I was able make the Maven fill correctly the `ambiente.producao` variable in the `web.xml` copied to the `target` directory.

However, when I start the Tomcat and print the the producao init param, It is showed `${ambiente.producao}`. Actually, when I open the `web.xml` present in the directory `[WORKSPACE_DIR]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/sinpo-web/WEB-INF`, the `producao` is not filled as it should be. It was like Eclipse (or WTP or Maven) had chosen the original file instead of filled file.

Therefore, I ask if there is some missing configuration needed to make the Maven (or Eclipse) publish using the files in `target` directory instead the original file.

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: Why not starting with working example?

Comment: @SkorpEN: Do you want say create a new project from scratch?

Comment: Start with working example and then step by step replace some parts with Your project.