# Changing web.xml depending on certain System.getProperty()

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

Is it possible to use or alternate the used web.xml on an environment based basis?

I am using maven, and i am thinking that it might be possible to switch?

Comment: It's possible *not* to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: how to fill a variable in web.xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566267/maven-how-to-fill-a-variable-in-web-xml-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

[maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Then send your system parameter using command line

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P %your env_var%
```

Or use [maven-antrun-plugin](http://devblog.virtage.com/2013/04/embed-and-run-ant-tasks-and-scripts-from-maven/) so you can process the env variable in ant  of without e [contrib-if](https://jaysonlorenzen.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/apache-ant-if-else-condition-without-ant-contrib/)