# maven-war-plugin not filtering on local

Tags: maven, filtering, web.xml, maven-war-plugin

I've been trying to use maven-war-plugin to filter web.xml with profile defined properties, and I made it work on deploying but not on my local server (Apache Tomcat 7.0.65).

I have this on web.xml

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>variableName</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>${property.variableName}</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

This on pom.xml

```
<property.variableName>This is a variable</property.variableName>
```

And this on the code:

```
InitialContext init = new InitialContext();
String variable = (String)init.lookup("java:comp/env/variableName");
```

The fact is that... on the generated web.xml (target/...web.xml), the variable is filtered with the new value, but deploying on local when I try to print the 'variable' value is logs ${property.variableName}

Any idea about how to fix this?

Thanks in advance and regards,

Comment: How are you deploying to your local server?  Are you copying over the war?  Are you using the cargo plugin?

Comment: I add the web project to the resources list on a tomcat server and then 'start the server' (I'm using eclipse sts).
When I compile the project, the generated web.xml on target folder have the values filtered, so I can deploy the .war file into a remote server, but when deploying on localhost it seems to take the source web.xml as it is with no value filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work. Seemed to be something related with deployment assembly which was not recognizing some folders or something like that.

The following post helped me to find it:
[Maven: how to fill a variable in web.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566267/maven-how-to-fill-a-variable-in-web-xml-file?answertab=votes#tab-top)